# Animate FAB button like Gmail Compose Button in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Am working on a `button` that animates like Gmail Compose Button. The behavior is such that on scrolling up it shrinks to a circle with icon at center while on scrolling downwards it expands to show icon and text. My implantation works well, but the issue now is that I want a fade like effect for the text such that after the FAB button expands, the text fades in smoothly rather than appearing abruptly.

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  bool isLoaded = false;
  bool upDirection = true, flag = true;
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  
    _scrollController
      ..addListener(() {
        upDirection = _scrollController.position.userScrollDirection ==
            ScrollDirection.forward;

        // makes sure we don't call setState too much, but only when it is needed
        if (upDirection != flag) setState(() {});
        flag = upDirection;
      });
  }

 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
    return new Scaffold(
     
       
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            controller: _scrollController,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
               
          Positioned(
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
            right: 20.0,
            child: AnimatedContainer(
                width: flag ? 170 : 56,
                height: 56,
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                child: FloatingActionButton.extended(
                    backgroundColor: AppColors.customFabRed,
                    heroTag: null,
                    onPressed: () {
                    
                    },
                    icon: flag
                        ? Icon(
                            Icons.call,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          )
                        : null,
                    label: flag
                        ? AnimatedOpacity( //trying to get the text to fade in after the fab is expanded but nothing happens
                      opacity: flag ? 1.0 : 0.0,
                      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 9000),
                          child: Text(
                              'Call a doctor',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 13.5,
                                height: 1.5,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                fontFamily: 'Euclid',
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                        )
                        : Icon(
                            Icons.call,
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ))),
          ),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }

 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try below code hope it helps to you :

Declare one Boolean variable

```
bool isFABExtended = false;
```

Create function for button action change:

```
  void _switchButton() {
    setState(
      () {
        isFABExtended = !isFABExtended;
      },
    );
  }
```

Declare your Widget:

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
    onPressed: _switchButton,
    label: AnimatedSwitcher(
      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
      transitionBuilder: (Widget child, Animation<double> animation) =>
          FadeTransition(
        opacity: animation,
        child: SizeTransition(
          child: child,
          sizeFactor: animation,
          axis: Axis.horizontal,
        ),
      ),
      child: isFABExtended
          ? Icon(Icons.check)
          : Row(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 4.0),
                  child: Icon(Icons.add),
                ),
                Text("Add Button")
              ],
            ),
    ),
  ),
```

Your Button Look like [image] and [image]

Comment: Thanks. this saved me a lot of time.