# Change the shape of Floating action button in Flutter

Tags: flutter, floating-action-button

I am trying to create a Floating action button which uses both with and without extended.

My requirement is when the page is scrolled floating action button should change from extended to with out extended. The issue i am facing is that the shape is not changing into circle. Below i have attached the code and screenshot.

```
FloatingActionButton.extended(
          label: AnimatedSwitcher(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
            transitionBuilder: (Widget child, Animation<double> animation) => FadeTransition(
              opacity: animation.drive(CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeIn)),
              child: SizeTransition(
                child: child,
                sizeFactor: animation,
                axis: Axis.horizontal,
              ),
            ),
            child: isExtended
                ? SvgPicture.asset(
                  floatIcon,
                )
                : Row(
                    children: [
                      SvgPicture.asset(
                        floatIcon,
                      ),
                      const Text(
                        ' New',
                        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Gilroy Medium', fontSize: 20, color: Color(0xffB0B0B0)),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          elevation: 0,
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
```

screenshot:

[image: Need to change the shape to circle]

Can anyone please help me on this issue.

Comment: You want to Gmail app **Compose** like float button? if yes then refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68905406/13997210) hope its help to you

Comment: Thanks for the response, my concern is that when the button is not expanded its not changing the shape to circle.

Comment: Are you see this answer? please try to run this hope its work to you.

Comment: Yes i saw your answer and i tried that as well, again i am not getting the circle shape. Even the link which you shared doesn't change into circle shape

Comment: Ok, I will try.

Comment: check my below answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below code,or you can used [**`flutter_scrolling_fab_animated`**](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_scrolling_fab_animated) package

Declare one Boolean variable

```
bool isFABExtended = false;
```

Create function for button action change:

```
  void _switchButton() {
    setState(
      () {
        isFABExtended = !isFABExtended;
      },
    );
  }
```

Declare your Widget:

```
 floatingActionButton: isFABExtended
      ? FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: _switchButton,
          child: Icon(Icons.check),
        )
      : FloatingActionButton.extended(
          onPressed: _switchButton,
          label: Row(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 4.0),
                child: Icon(Icons.add),
              ),
              Text("Add Button")
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Extended `FloatingActionButton` Result Screen -> [image]

Circular `FloatingActionButton` result-> [image]

Comment: Thanks for you response, i just tried to implement with the AnimatedSwitcher but couldn't find that, I will use the package which you have suggested. Thank You!!

Comment: @Elam happy to help you enjoy your ride with flutter

Comment: I just added the shape inside the FloatingActionButton.extended to some extent its working fine without using the package.