# Why does this FAB not animate to an extended one?

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, floating-action-button

So I want to animate a fab between extended and normal like Gmail

but my FABs refuse to animate this just change immediately

This is my code:

```dart
return Scaffold(
      appBar: appBar,
      body: Center(
        <Code of no interest>
      ),
      floatingActionButton: isFABOpen
          ? FloatingActionButton.extended(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddQuote()),
                );
              },
              label: Text('Add Quote'),
              icon: Icon(Icons.add_rounded),
            )
          : FloatingActionButton(
            
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AddQuote()),
                );
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.add_rounded),
            ),

      floatingActionButtonAnimator: FloatingActionButtonAnimator.scaling,
    );
```

Comment: Refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68905406/13997210) hope it's helpful to you

Comment: You can chack my solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72010826/2648670